What is an almost discrete space that isn't semiregular like?
Let us say that a space $X$ is almost discrete if all of its points except for one are isolated, i.e. there exists a non-isolated point $p\in X$ such that $p\not\in U\subseteq X$ implies $U$ is open.
A space is semiregular if it admits a basis of "regular open" sets, that is it admits a basis $\mathcal B$ such that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}B=B$ for all $B\in\mathcal B$.
By inspection, nearly every almost discrete space is semiregular, but what is an almost discrete space that isn't semiregular like?

Impressively, being almost discrete but not semiregular is enough to fully characterize a space up to cardinality: any such space must be the disjoint union of the Sierpiński space and a (possibly empty) discrete space. Conversely, any such union is almost discrete but not semiregular.
First, we assess which sets can obstruct semiregularity.
Any open neighborhood of the non-isolated point $p$ is closed and so equals the interior of its closure.
Every other point of the space has a smallest neighborhood (its singleton set), so each of these sets must be present in any basis. Furthermore, any other set not containing $p$ can be omitted from the basis as the union of such singletons.
Thus, there must be some point $q\neq p$ such that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\{q\}\neq\{q\}$.
Note that the closure of any set $A\not\ni p$ must be either $A$ or $A\cup\{p\}$. (This is because $A$ is either closed itself or contained in the closed set $A\cup\{p\}$ with no other set strictly in between.)
Since it cannot be that $\operatorname{cl}\{q\}=\{q\}$, we find that $\operatorname{cl}\{q\}=\{q,p\}$.
It also cannot be that $\operatorname{int}\{q,p\}=\{q\}$, so $\operatorname{int}\{q,p\}=\{q,p\}$.
Thus, $\{q,p\}$ is both closed and open, so the space equals the disjoint union of it and its complement. $\{q,p\}$ is homeomorphic to the Sierpiński space as (by assumption) $\{q\}$ is open and $\{p\}$ is not, and its complement is discrete as all of its singletons are open.
